# How to Turn Data in Rows into Data in Columns but only when the rows share a key element in common (Pivot a table into a matrix?)

Tags: google-sheets

My student information system gives me multiple rows per student, each row showing one period in their schedule. I want rearrange the data so each row is the complete schedule for one student. Put another way, my source gives me:

[image]

What I want is this:
[image]

Comment: Glad to share link to my sheet if that would help. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nkRDUZLMClwhq5kZIdtikNGCuSLx_8_hZ6vCDeWQZbk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use `query()` with a `pivot` clause, like this:

`=query(A1:C21, "select A, max(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B", 1)`

If you need to handle multiple blocks listed in one cell in column `B`, you will have to split the column and insert additional rows.

Comment: Good job,doubleunary.
Before using your formula he will have to modify the row (or rows) that contain a double Block, such as cell B21, and add a new row, so that he can then extend the calculation to the whole WhatIGot!A1:C

Comment: Yes! Excellent.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)